# Query - I need to only select users with data in a specific column

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, subscriber

Here is an example of the TABLE that I have:

```
ID   |  Locale | GUID
088     US       tasffsddf124312
088     US
088     US       tasffsd321123
```

I want to be able to ONLY select users WITH data in the GUID-column and exclude the ones with no data in the GUI-column.

**Here is what I have:**

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE TACTIC_ID = '0088'
    AND LOCALE = 'US'
    AND ACTIVE = '1'
    AND TRIM(IFNULL(GUID, '')) <> ''
```

This does not work in Marketing Cloud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking for `GUID IS NOT NULL` should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE TACTIC_ID = '0088'
    AND LOCALE = 'US'
    AND ACTIVE = '1'
    AND GUID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I think you mean "AND GUID IS NOT NULL". Null matches nothing, so that last line would evaluate to false whether GUID is null or populated with some value.

Comment: If you want to filter out empty values ('') as well as NULL then you may want to do: AND ISNULL(GUID, '') <> ''